# import to cleardb from existing MYSQL database

Tags: mysql, asp.net, azure

I have created a Microsoft Azure asp.net website and also leased out a mysql cleardb database. Is there a way I can import all the tables which I have created in my local MySQL database into cleardb cloud database?

I also could not find out how to create a table in ClearDB on cloud. I am a newbie and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Install the [phpMyAdmin site extention](https://www.siteextensions.net/packages/phpmyadmin/) from the [Site Extensions Gallery](https://www.siteextensions.net/packages) to your Web Site.

Using phpMyAdmin you can [export/import database](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/). And you can also execute database queries (such as CREATE TABLE or SELECT ..., any DB queries).

For your local database, you can use various tools to generate export script. Like [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/), which also [supports export/import functions.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still unable to understand after exporting from MYSQL, how do I import in Cleardb on cloud? Microsoft Azure management portal where my cleardb database sits does not seem to give an option to import databases at all.